# Conditional Expected Value formula

Tags: probability

In a large population of patients, 20% have early stage cancer, 10% have advanced stage cancer, and the other 70% do not have cancer. Six patients from this population are randomly selected.

Calculate the expected number of selected patients with advanced stage cancer, given that at least one of the selected patients has early stage cancer.

This is what I have so far:

Let X = number of patients that has early stage cancer

Let Y = number of patients that has advanced stage cancer

And I tried to use the definition of conditional expectation values

My Solution so far
Need to find the $E[y/x\geq1]$

$E[y]=E[y/x=0]*p(x=0)+E[y/x\geq1]*p(x\geq1)$

$E[y]=6*0.1=0.6$

$p(x=0)=(1-0.2)^6=0.26$

$p(x\geq 1)1-0.26=0.74$

don't know how to find $E[y/x=0]$ or  $E[y/x\geq1] 
 $